# Is there a hash function for binary data which produces closer hashes when the data is more similar?

Tags: algorithm, file, compare

I'm looking for something like a hash function but for which it's output is closer the closer two different inputs are?

Something like:

```
f(1010101) = 0 #original hash

f(1010111) = 1 #very close to the original hash as they differ by one bit
f(0101010) = 9999 #not very close to the original hash they all bits are different
```

(example outputs for demonstration purposes only)

All of the input data will be of the same length.

I want to make comparisons between a file a lots of other files and be able to determine which other file has the fewest differences from it.

Comment: hashing is not the right way to tackle this problem

Comment: I know, that's why I'm not looking for a hash function as such.

Comment: You have to define 'similarity' first for each pair of input elements.

Comment: Are you looking for locality-sensitive hashing?

Comment: @Peter: I mean forget about unary functions, you're looking for a binary one which calculates similarity between the files.

Comment: @The Nail Just bitwise: if they are exactly the same bit-for-bit then the output must be equal, for any one-bit difference the output should be "less than" (in some sense) any two bit difference, and so on.

Comment: @Peter ok how about this: you xor the two sources, and take the population count of that.

Comment: @harold I'm not great with bitwise operations, what are the advantages/output behaviour of this approach?

Comment: @Peter well it calculates exactly what you suggested really - it would give the number of bits that are not the same in both files.

Comment: @harold: this is the best solution. you should really post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this algorithm.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Since this is string only.
You may convert all your binary to string
for example:
0 -> "00000000"
1 -> "00000001"

Comment: this is a huge overkill, and if you're interested only in bit differences it can even give wrong results

Comment: base64 encoding would be more efficient for this I guess

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in either [simhashing](http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/) or [shingling](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/near-duplicates-and-shingling-1.html).

If you are only trying to detect similarity between documents, there are other techniques that may suit you better (like [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf).)  The second link is part of a good book whose other chapters delve into general information retrieval topics, including these other techniques.

Comment: simhash looks great but it seems to be designed for textual data, whereas I'm working with binary data. Is there a specific version for binary data? A quick google suggests not. If that's the case is it reasonable to choose 8-bit bytes as my "features"?

Comment: That depends on your data.  If there are natural units within it, you might choose those.  If not, individual bytes might still be too granular.  In that case I'd try "n-grams" of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the source code to unix utilities like `cmp` or the `FileCmp` stuff in Python and use that to try to determine a reasonable algorithm.

In my uninformed opinion, calculating a hash is not likely to work well.  First, it can be expensive to calculate a hash.  Second, what you're trying to do sounds more like a job for encoding than a hash; once you start thinking of it that way, it's not clear that it's even worth transforming the file that way.

If you have some constraints, specifying them might be useful. For example, if all the files are the exact same length, that may simplify things.  Or if you are only interested in differences between bits in the same position and not interested in things that are similar only if you compare bits in different positions (e.g., two files are identical, except that one has everything shifted three bits--should those be considered similar or not similar?).

Comment: Will edit question, but in this particular case all files will be of the same length, and I'm ambivalent to location of differences.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a hash for this.

You must compute signatures containing several characteristic values like :

- file name
- file size
- Is binary / Is ascii only
- date (if needed)

some other more complex like :

- variance of the values of bytes
- average value of bytes
- average length of same value bits sequence (in compressed files there are no long identical bit sequences)
- ...

Then you can compare signatures.

But the most important is to know what kind of data is in these files. If it is images, the size and main color are more important. If it is sound, you could analyse only some frequencies...

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate the population count of the XOR of the two files, which is exactly the number of bits that are not the same between the two files. So it just does precisely what you asked for, no approximations.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent your data as a binary vector of features and then use **[dimensionality reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_reduction)** either with [SVD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) or with [random indexing](http://www.sics.se/~mange/papers/RI_intro.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a file fingerprint of sorts.  For plain text,  something like Nilsimsa (http://ixazon.dynip.com/~cmeclax/nilsimsa.html) works reasonably well.

There are a variety of different names for this type of technique.  Fuzzy Hashing/Locality Sensitive Hashing/Distance Based Hashing/Dimensional reduction and a few others.  Tools can generate a fixed length output or variable length output, but the outputs are generally comparable (eg by levenshtein distance) and similar inputs yield similar outputs.

The link above for nilsimsa gives two similar spam messages and here are the example outputs:

```
773e2df0a02a319ec34a0b71d54029111da90838cbc20ecd3d2d4e18c25a3025 spam1
47182cf0802a11dec24a3b75d5042d310ca90838c9d20ecc3d610e98560a3645 spam2
 *  * ** *** * ** ** ** **     *  *******  **** **     *    *  *
```

Spamsum and sdhash are more useful for arbitrary binary data.  There are also algorithms specifically for images that will work regardless of whether it's a jpg or a png.  Identical images in different formats wouldn't be noticed by eg spamsum.